# How do I move avro files to kafka via a kafka connector?

Tags: avro, apache-kafka-connect

I found the CSV Source Connector which can monitor a directory for files and reads them as CSVs.
Is there a Avro Source Connector for avro files? 
if it is not, Any recommendation for dealing with reading AVRO files to Kafka via Kafka connect?

Comment: Here is a connector for streaming files into Kafka. Currenlty, Avro is not supported but the connector can be easily extended (by implementing a new FileInputReader). You can also open an issue to add Avro : https://github.com/streamthoughts/kafka-connect-file-pulse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source connector [Kafka Connect File Pulse](https://github.com/streamthoughts/kafka-connect-file-pulse) support Avro files since version 1.1.0.

To read avro files you have to configure the connector to use the class: '`io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.reader.AvroFileInputReader`'

Here is a simple configuration example : [Avro Configuration](https://github.com/streamthoughts/kafka-connect-file-pulse/blob/master/config/connect-file-pulse-quickstart-avro.json)

For more information see : [Documentation](https://streamthoughts.github.io/kafka-connect-file-pulse/)